# Python multiprocessing + subprocess issues

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, nfs

I have a binary (say `a.out`) that I want to call with different configs. I want to run these configs on a 40-core machine in parallel. Below is a sketch of my code.

It is very straightforward: I generate a config and pass in into the worker, and the worker calls the binary with the config using subprocess. I am also redirecting the output to a file. Let's call this piece of code `run.py`

```
def worker(cmdlist, filename):
    outputfile = open(filename, 'wb')
    // here it essentially executes  a.out config > outputfile
    subprocess.call(cmdlist, stderr=outputfile, stdout=outputfile) 
    outputfile.close()

def main():
    pool = Pool(processes = 40)
    for config in all_configs
        filename, cmdlist = genCmd(config)
        res = pool.apply_async(worker, [cmdlist, filename])
        results.append(res)
    for res in results:
        res.get()
    pool.close()
```

But after I kick it off, I realized that I am not spawning as many processes as I want. I definitely submitted more than 40 workers, but in top, I am only seeing about 20 of a.out.

I do see many of the run.py that are in "sleeping" state (i.e., "S" in top). When I do a `ps auf`, I also saw a lot of run.py in "S+" state, with no binary spawned out. Only about half of them spawned "a.out"

I am wondering, why is this happening? I am redirecting the output to a network-mounted hard-drive, which could be a reason, but in top I only see 10%wa (which in my understanding is 10% of the time waiting for IO). I don't think this results in 50% of idle CPUs. Plus, I should at least have the binary spawned out, instead of being stuck at `run.py`. My binary's runtime is also long enough. I should really be seeing 40 jobs running for a long time.

Any other explanation? Anything I did wrong in my python code?

Comment: How many configs do you have in all_configs?

Comment: @JoshRagem much more than 40, as I said in the original question

Comment: Try to add notable delay to the a.out.

Comment: If you let it run till the end, does the output show evidence of all the tasks? Have you checked to make sure that the tasks do not run if you don't see them?

Comment: For similar tasks I like to use something like `xargs -n 1 -P 40 a.out <parameters_file` to keep 40 a.out processes running, each with a parameter that comes from parameters_file which could have thousands of parameters.  May need to replace a.out with a small script if a complex command line needs to be built based on parameters.

Comment: If you have an mwe of what you ended up doing, an update would be appreciated. Did you end up not using Pool at all, as suggested by @JT. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach I have used to make use of many simultaneous processes running at once on multiple cores is to use p = subprocess.Popen(...) and p.Poll().  In your case I think you would be able to skip using Pool altogether.  I'd give you a better example but unfortunately I don't have access to that code anymore.